# Problem in calculating probability without integration

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Please help me. This is my assignment problem.
We know the following integral for the particle in a one-dimensional box
$\int_{0}^{L/5}\psi_5^2 (x)dx=\frac{1}{5}$.
How does this value compare to that for the integral over the same range, but using $\psi_1$ instead of $\psi_5$? (Larger, smaller, or equal?). I calculated integration. It is less that $\frac{1}{5}$. Can we get this decision without integrating?  Here both $\psi_1, \psi_5$ are normalised and box is from 0 to $L$.

Comment: [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)

Comment: You haven’t explained what $\psi_1$ and $\psi_5$ are.

Comment: Those are normalised.

Comment: *Can we get this decision without integrating?* Did you make a sketch, as the original problem statement suggested?

Comment: Is the reader supposed to assume that the box extends from $0$ to $L$? Sometimes the box is taken to be from $-L/2$ to $L/2$, or from $-L$ to $L$.